# CoroutineScope Questions

Tags: android, coroutine, coroutinescope

At the Coroutine Scope,
Why is the last println() called first when the launch block is called first?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `launch` function will start a new coroutine, which is an async action, and it usually takes a few milliseconds to finish, but meanwhile, the main tread goes through to the next statement, so the end statements will be printed first.

Answer (score 1):

Hej BrianLee,

within the `runBlocking` you start two new coroutines without blocking the current thread when calling `launch{}`. So the block inside `runBlocking` continues and the `println`s are executed.

If you want to want for the `launch`-blocks to finish first, you have to make your thread wait for its execution by use `.join()` on its `Job`

```
runBlocking {
 val job = launch {
   println("launch : ${Thread.currentThread() .name}")
   println("launch 1")
 }

 job.join()
 
 println("runBlocking: ${Thread. currentThread () .name}")
 println("runBlockging")
}
```

Link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#an-explicit-job

Answer (score 0):

Launch is a coroutine builder. It launches a new coroutine concurrently with the rest of the code, which continues to work independently. That's why outside code is executed and printed first.

**Try with suspend function with coroutineScope**

**Use suspend function**

> Reference take here. Mentioned in kotlin docs https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder

```
fun main() = runBlocking{  
 doWork()
}
fun doWork() = coroutineScope{  

  launch{
    //your code here
    }
}
```